# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: stub class initialization failed

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, rmi

I am working on a web application which uses *Eclipse Juno ver - 1.5.0*, hosted on *Tomcat 7.0*. Additionally, the application is also using remote method invocation.

After an update made in the code, I cleaned the tomcat directory. This resulted in removal of few essential *.class* files from the following directory

*.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp2/wtpwebapps/trusteddataaggwebsite/WEB-INF/classes*

Apparently rebuilding the project did not restore the removed files. So, I manually restored the missing .class files. Although one of the missing files was the TSDAVis_Stub.class file.

As such I recompiled the stub using *rmic* command to generate the stub. But on execution I am getting the following error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: stub class initialization failed
trusteddataagg.TSDAVis_Stub.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.java:25)
sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:122)
java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Field.java:918)
java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:899)
java.lang.reflect.Field.getLong(Field.java:528)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getDeclaredSUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:1614)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$700(ObjectStreamClass.java:52)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:425)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:413)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:310)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:547)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1582)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1495)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1731)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:84)
ParaselectionServlet.doPost(ParaselectionServlet.java:128)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

I understand the code description is a bit vague, but it would be really helpful if anyone can shed some light on

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: stub class initialization failed
```

More specifically, if this error is related to RMI or some configuration problem.

Thank You.

Comment: Clean and rebuild everything again and this time stop and restart the Registry. Also please show the `rmic` command you used.

Comment: I did try cleaning and rebuilding. I even removed the project from the eclipse and re-imported. Similarly, I removed it from and tomcat and re-added and re-published the project. Same for the RMI registry. It has not resolved the issue.

Comment: For the rmic command:
I used javac *.java in the src folder of the server project
Then, I used:
rmic trusteddataagg.TSDAVis
It compiled without flagging any errors.
I then moved the generated stub.class file inside the metadata directory listed in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved when the project was migrated onto another machine. Apparently the error had nothing to with incorrectness related to RMI. Although, the cause of the error and why it didn't resolve  even after re-building the project is still unknown.